# how to make the div outside svg unclickable

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I have:

```
<div id="workarea"> <style id="styleoverrides" type="text/css" media="screen" scoped="scoped"></style> <div id="svgcanvas" style="position:relative"> </div> </div>
```

and inside div id svgcanvas i am generating the svg named : svgroot

The problem is that i want the user to click the svgcanvas and its svg, but outside svgcanvas in workarea i need to have unclickable.

for this i have done :

```
  #svgcanvas {
        line-height: normal;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #A0A0A0;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 640px;
        height: 480px;
        -apple-dashboard-region:dashboard-region(control rectangle 0px 0px 0px 0px); /* for widget regions that shouldn't react to dragging */
        position: relative;
        /* 
          A subtle gradient effect in the canvas.
          Just experimenting - not sure if this is worth it.
        */.... so on
   }
```

and

```
#workarea {
    display: inline-table-cell;
    position:absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 14px;
    background-color: #A0A0A0;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;

}
```

I have also used `pointer-events: none;` in the #workarea but it also make svgcanvas unclickable.
I want to have workarea unclickable while svgcanvas clickable.

Comment: What exactly is the issue with clicking on a div?

Comment: The issue is that my image is only on the svgcanvas and if someone click outside it also draws outside the picture which i dont want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by this I guess

`#workarea{ cursor: default; }`

`#svgcanvas {
cursor:pointer;
}`

`$("#svgcanvas").click(function() { //do your stuff });`

Comment: It is not working and showing the same responce either i click canvas or workarea it executes the function

Comment: can u please share your code in fiddle or somewhere. Will help to better answer your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this just plain CSS?

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `<area shape="rect" coords="27,67,435,267" */insert cords of div here/* href="" alt="" title="">` could help out?

Comment: I think this solution will not help since my division size is not fixed and also i have a division inside it which i want to click